# Ajax - Back button?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$("a").click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('href') != '#') {
        if (strpos($(this).attr('href'), 'mob.php') !== false) {
            $.ajax({
              url: $(this).attr('href')+"&logo=0",
              cache: false,
              success: function(html){
                $("#ajax").html(html);
              }
            });
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is that when someone presses the back button they leave the website instead of going back to the previous page. Is there a work around for this?